# Will conda virtual environment affect performance?

Tags: conda

As conda can create a virtual environment to keep the dependence of certain packages
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html#virtual-environments
I am wondering if the virtual environment will affect the performance of a program inside this environment, i.e., will it slow down some program comparing with running without the virtual environment.

Comment: Probably not, no.

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope not.

Comment: If you have a specific application in mind, do mention it. Of course, the best would be to actually measure the performance and compare.

Comment: Environment activation is mostly a matter of managing shell environment variables, so no, it should not impact actual software performance.